# How to make the seekbar thumb not exceed the progress margin?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

When creating my custom `seekBar` I'm having problems, because the thumb is exceeding the progress bar of the seekBar, I would like the thumb to reach the end of the seekbar margin without exceeding it, Problem:

[image: Problem]

I wanted the thumb not to go beyond the progress bar of the seekbar just touching its margin. E.g.:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Linear code of seekbar:

```java
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, dp(30));
linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);       
layoutParams.setMargins(dp(3), dp(1), dp(2), dp(4));       
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);       linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
linearLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(1);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Code of seekbar:

```java
        seekBar.setProgressDrawable(seekbarProgressOff);
        seekBar.setPadding(25, 10, 35, 10);
        seekBar.setSplitTrack(false);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, dp(18)));
        seekBar.setMax(max);
        seekBar.setProgress(prog);
        seekBar.setElevation(0);
        seekBar.setProgressDrawable(seekbarProgressOff);
        seekBar.setPadding(25, 10, 35, 10);
        seekBar.setSplitTrack(false);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, dp(18)));
        seekBar.setMax(max);
        seekBar.setProgress(prog);
        seekBar.setElevation(0);
```

Thanks for help.